# Does "to shift friends" mean "to replace" or "to make different"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/shift):
to shift - to put (something) aside and replace it by another or others; change or exchange:
*to shift friends*

Does "to shift friends" mean "to replace friends with other friends" or "to make friends different"?

Comment: Please give context.

Comment: I've never heard such an expression! You need to tell us where you heard or read this.

Comment: I've added the link.

Comment: @Loviii, Stick with good, reliable dictionaries like Oxford and Merriam-Webster. These online-only dictionaries like dictionary.com and thefreedictionary.com are run by people who bought catchy domain names, not by organizations with long histories and reputations to maintain. "To shift friends" is unnatural. I'd have to stretch my mind to figure out what it possibly could mean.

Comment: I've never heard this usage from an American. I have heard a usage in Singapore where "shift" is used for moving heavy objects like furniture or industrial equipment.

Comment: What @gotube said. The usage *does* exist, and the first example I found was *To account for the 10° minimum approach temperature, we **shifted hot and cold stream interval temperature scales***. But shifting friends is just weird.

Comment: @gotube the reason I can use a lot of dictionaries is that sometimes there is not enough explanation or examples to me to understand a word meaning. That's why I have to look it up on dictionary.com, thefreedictionary.com or some others.

Answer (score 3):

According to dictionary.com's definition, it means *to replace friends with others* - but I find that definition surprising. It isn't listed by Oxford Languages (google *shift definition* and click on 'more definitions').

Oxford says (in the note at the bottom) that the meaning *change, replace* is Middle English. The sense 'change one's clothes' occurs in Samuel Pepys' Diary (1660s), for example "I shifted myself into a riding-habitt", but it isn't used nowadays.

Comment: The OED 2nd ed includes for shift (verb)  trans. To change, to replace by another of the kind. **With plural object: To quit one and take another of (the things indicated).** I think it's somewhat archaic - earliest of the quoted uses is 1250 and the last is 1864 (and that's Lord Tennyson).

Comment: It definitely isn't common, either in Google search or Google Books. I've found some uses in an educational/child development context e.g. *32 Ways to Become a Great Sunday School Teacher*, Delia Halverson, 1997 mentions that young children "enjoy 'best friends' but may shift friends: peer cliques and clubs shift easily". So it might be used in such specialised contexts but not elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

To 'shift' with the meaning you found is usually used with regards to oneself e.g. "To lose weight, I shifted my focus/efforts to eating less rather than exercising more" or "To progress at work, I shifted my focus towards a more managerial role rather than technical".

When talking about friends, the usual verbs are find or make - "I needed to find some better friends", "After moving to a new area, I had to make new friends".

I think there is a subtle undertone that to 'find' implies changing friends, whereas 'make' implies that you've need extra friends without losing the ones you already have, but that might just be me.

As a native English speaker of over 50 years, I've never heard "shift" in connection with friends, although you could, of course, shift your efforts to making/finding new/better friends.